# How to set the DisplayMemberPath in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm struggling with the Wpf `DataGrid`. Its `ItemsSource` is a `DataTable` where is composed by type cells `Tuple<int, string>`

Here is a little snippet code about how can I create my `DataTable`.

```
            // Create columns
            for (int j = 0; j < maxCount; j++) {
                dt.Columns.Add(selectedTests[i].Name + " " + (j + 1).ToString(), typeof(Tuple<int, string>));
            }

            // Create rows 
            for (int k = 0; k < tuple.Item2.Count; k++) {
                var newRow = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }

            ...
            dt.Rows[k][i + m] = new Tuple<int, string>(n, str);
```

Then I set this `DataTable` to my `DataGrid` and I want to show only the property `Item2` from the tuple, I need to preserver the tuple instance at this moment. And can't define my columns to set the `displaymemberPath` because the is autogenerated.

```
    <DataGrid  x:Name="dataGrid" LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow_1" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Item2}">
```

All the time my datagrid converts to string my tuple something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885711/wpf-c-bind-datagrid-column-with-code-behind) says, you can set binding with your code-behind.

So, you can subscribe the `yourgrid_AutoGeneratingColumn` event and do this:

```
(e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding = new Binding("Title");
```

*certainly you should pass your `ColumnName` into `AutoGeneratingColumn` event by some solutions...*

Answer (score -1):

You just need to Manually set the column and bind it to the Item2 column.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataTablePropertyInYourDataContext}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Item2" 
            Binding="{Binding ColumnNameInYourDataTable}" 
            />
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

OR another workaround : You can subscribe for the AutoGeneratingColumn event, set Cancel when column not desired equals to true. take a look at this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Hope that helps

Comment: But as I tell you, I'm not generating manually my columns, I really unknown the count of columns

Comment: I don't know if I get your issue.Can you add desired DataGrid columns and their bindings dynamically ?

Comment: Yes, I mea, they're being created automatically with `AutoGenerateColumns` datagrid property

Comment: Updated my answer, please explain your goal a little more in case this dosen't resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, also I was looking for that event but I still can't accomplish. As you can see in the image I'm setting to the cell a `Tuple<int, string>` with `AutoGenerateColumns` property set to true.  And I'm looking to implement something like a `DisplayMemberPath` to the cell. I mean show the `Item2` in th dataGrid from the tuple but contains the current value (Tuple..)

Comment: Try using DisplayMemberPath property at the column level then, although I think that this property needs the column's ItemsSource property to be filled too.

Comment: I can't find that property

Comment: this unfortunately concerns ComboBoxColumn in WPFToolkit, maybe you can workaround this with by overriding ComboBoxColumn style to get it displaying one item like a label.