# Add check box column in wpf datagrid dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am using WPF datagrid to display details using MVVM. Columns for this datagrid are dynamically defined at run time according to the user. It is working fine. However, I am in need to include on "checkbox" column in this datagrid dynamically along with existing fields. I have used following code.

...

```
foreach (var column in collection)
{
  GridColumnAdd(gridView, column);
}
```

...

```
private static void GridColumnAdd(DataGrid gridView, DataGridColumns columnName)
    {

        if (columnName.DisplayColumnName == "Print")
        {
            var column = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();

            column.Header = columnName.DisplayColumnName;
            column.Binding = new Binding();

            var binding = (column.Binding as Binding);
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

            if (binding != null)
            {
                IValueConverter converter = binding.Converter = new ColumnValueConverter(); // Will work here
                binding.ConverterParameter = columnName.BindingPropertyName;
            }

            gridView.Columns.Add(column);

        }
        else
        {
            var column = new DataGridTextColumn();

            column.IsReadOnly = true;
            column.Header = columnName.DisplayColumnName;
            column.Binding = new Binding();
            var binding = (column.Binding as Binding);
            if (binding != null)
            {
                IValueConverter converter = binding.Converter = new ColumnValueConverter(); // Will work here
                binding.ConverterParameter = columnName.BindingPropertyName;
            }
            gridView.Columns.Add(column);

        }
    }
```

while running this I am getting following exception "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath".

Could you please help me to include checkbox column in the existing datagrid column dynamically?

Comment: Why don't you add columns from the xaml. I mean is there any specific need of defining columns in code behind C# code?

Comment: Yes, based on the user, we are displaying the columns in the datagrid. So, the checkbox is one of the required column for some users.

Comment: The error is clear, you need to define a path for defining two way binding and I cannot see any path defined in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the path in `Binding()` consturctor as `Binding("IsChecked")`.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885711/wpf-c-bind-datagrid-column-with-code-behind) link and you'll get some help. If you still don't get how to do it. Add a comment to this answer.