# WPF Datagrid flatten collections of collection objects

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need your help. I have a collection of objects which has collections inside and I need to display the values inside of them.

This is my collection Element. A List of them will later be bound to the Datagrid (ObjectBase is only an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
public class ElementContainer : ObjectBase
{
    public Element ContainerElement { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<State> _elementStates;

    public ObservableCollection<State> ElementStates
    {
        get { return _elementStates; }
        set { _elementStates = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

My elements:

```
public class Element
{
    public int Nbr { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class State: ObjectBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool _value;

    public bool Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string StateType { get; set; }
}
```

The "Value" property of the State object is what I need get updated if it changed.

My ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ObjectBase
{

    private IList<ElementContainer> _enitites;

    public IList<ElementContainer> Enitites
    {
        get { return _enitites; }
        set { _enitites = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Enitites = new ObservableCollection<ElementContainer>()
        {
            new ElementContainer() {
                                       ContainerElement =  new Element() {Nbr= 1, Name= "Test 1" },
                                       ElementStates = new ObservableCollection<State>()
                                       {
                                            new State() { Name = "On", Value = true,  StateType= "On" },
                                            new State() { Name = "Open", Value = false,  StateType= "Open" }
                                       }
                                    },

             new ElementContainer() {
                                       ContainerElement =  new Element() {Nbr= 2, Name= "Test 2" },
                                       ElementStates = new ObservableCollection<State>()
                                       {
                                            new State() { Name = "On", Value = false, StateType= "On" },
                                            new State() { Name = "Open", Value = true, StateType= "Open" }
                                       }
                                    }

         };
    }
}
```

Now the Datagrid should have following columns:

Nbr, Name, On, Open

The CellValue of the "On" and "Open" columns should be the value property of the State.

Any ideas?

Edit:

What I also tried is to create an AttachedProperty for creating the columns:

```
public class ElementStatesGridExtensions
{
    public static ObservableCollection<ColumnConfig> GetColumnConfigs(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<ColumnConfig>)obj.GetValue(ColumnConfigsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetColumnConfigs(DependencyObject obj, ObservableCollection<ColumnConfig> value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ColumnConfigsProperty, value);
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnConfigsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColumnConfigs", typeof(ObservableCollection<ColumnConfig>), typeof(ElementStatesGridExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnColumnsChanged)));

    static DeviceStateConverter converter = new DeviceStateConverter();

    static FrameworkElementFactory CreateFrameWorkFactoryWithBinding(ColumnConfig config)
    {
        var fwf = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));

        if (config != null && config.ColumnType != null)
        {

            if (config.ColumnType.Equals("State"))
            {
                fwf.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("ElementStates")
                {
                    ConverterParameter = config.ColumnName,
                    Converter = converter,

                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
                });
            }
        }
        return fwf;
    }


    static void OnColumnsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = d as DataGrid;
        dataGrid.Columns.Clear();


        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Nbr", Binding = new Binding("ContainerElement.Nbr") });
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Name", Binding = new Binding("ContainerElement.Name") });


        foreach (var columnConfig in GetColumnConfigs(d))
        {
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn()
            {
                Header = columnConfig.ColumnHeader,
                CellTemplate = new DataTemplate()
                {
                    VisualTree = CreateFrameWorkFactoryWithBinding(columnConfig)
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

public class DeviceStateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is ObservableCollection<stof.State> deviceStates && parameter != null)
        {
            var deviceState = deviceStates.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StateType?.ToUpper() == parameter.ToString().ToUpper());

            if (deviceState != null)
                return deviceState.Value;

        }

        return false;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then I attached this property to the datagrid.
And added this ...

```
public void RefeshStates(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("ElementStates");
    }
```

to the ElementContainer class.

Then in the ViewModel I iterate through all entities and register the PropertyChanged event of every state to the ElementContainer. 
So now if the state value changes, the Container gets notified and the Collection will refresh. That's not a good solution. Also the states of all other elements will be updated.

```
 foreach (ElementContainer container in Enitites)
        {

            foreach (State s in container.ElementStates)
            {
                s.PropertyChanged += container.RefeshStates;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `ElementStates` length always 2? if yes than tere are two options:

1. Option 1: You can include both `State` values into your `ElementContainer` class as Properties.
2. Option 2: You can call something like this `var q = Enitites.Select(e=>e.Nbr, e.Name, e.ElementStates.Where(es=>es.Name="On").First().Value, e.ElementStates.Where(es=>es.Name="Open").First().Value);`

Comment: Hi Dimos.Thank you for your answer. No the number of the states varies depending on the element type. The user can later choose the elementtype and states which he wants do display. But he can only choose one elementtype. So all elements in the grid are the same type.

Comment: Are 'On' and 'Open' states always in the ElementStates list? If yes, then the 2nd Option will work

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The name of the states the the user wants to see are in the columnConfigs. Via Settings Dialog the user can f.e. select the elementtype "TV" and the states "IsOn" and "IsInputHDMI1" or he can select the elementtype "Door" and the state "IsOpen"

Comment: In that case you could add columns in code. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885711/wpf-c-bind-datagrid-column-with-code-behind for more infos. How many state types are avaliable?

Comment: Hi Dimos. thanks again for your answer. There are theoretically unlimited types of states available. Practically 3 to 10. I have edited the question. Binding in Code is what I have tried before but I didn't figured it out how to do this to only update the changed value.

Comment: Maybe following [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/09/30/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject/) can help you to create an dynamic object with dynamic properties. You could add all Statetypes defined in your configuration as properties and bind your new added columns to this properties.

Comment: That's an interesting hint. I give them a try and mark this as answer if it works. Thank you very much! kalhspera :-)

Comment: Glad to help. Inform me if somethig works not well. Καλησπέρα :)